# Where is the time stamp located in a file? Want to change it using assembly

Tags: assembly

Twenty years ago, when I was taking an assembly course, the professor gave a handout in which there was instruction of where the time stamp of a file was. With that information, I was able to change time stamp of files. Twenty years later, that knowledge, and the handout, was gone. Can't remember what kind of Windows system I was using, XP maybe?

Now, I would like to change the time stamp of few files (I'm using Windows 10). I searched the net and found several utilities and other ways of doing it but not assembly. I cannot find info on how to change time stamp in assembly. Can anyone help? Where is the time stamp in a file?

Comment: Why do you want to use assembly?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `stat` is for reading. For writing you need something like `utimes`.

Comment: Ahh, good point. So that would be `__NR_utime/__NR_utimes` (`0x84/0xeb` 64-bit)

Comment: @melpomene As strange as it may sound, I like assembly. This is not just how to change a time stamp but how to change it in assembly.

Comment: As usual, the answer is "the same way you do from C, by making the appropriate library function or system call".  Making system call from asm in general is a problem you only have to solve once for any given OS, by looking up how to do it (ABI/calling convention and where the OS documents their system call numbers / args.  Or in the case of Windows, they *don't* document a raw syscall ABI, so you need to use DLL functions to do it portably.)  Single step into the DLL calls if you're curious what machine code they contain.

Comment: Anyway, obviously there can't be a specific code answer without specifying an OS (like Linux, Solaris, Windows, z/OS) and a CPU architecture (like PowerPC, AArch64, or x86-64).

Answer (score 4):

> Where is the time stamp in a file?

It's not in the file's data. It's in meta-data that the file system associates with the file. For example, for FAT file systems, it's in the file's directory entry (an on-disk structure that contains the file's name, its size, where the first cluster of the file's data is on the disk, etc). To be more specific than that people would need to know exactly which file system it is.

To change the time stamp in assembly you'd need to know which timestamp you want to change (for most "Unix-like" systems there are three time stamps - creation time, access time and modification time) and possibly how you want to change the time stamp (setting access time or modification time to "now" may be done by accessing/modifying the file's data); and what kind of environment your code will be running in.

For examples:

a) if your code is running on a bare 80x86 machine with access to BIOS services, then you will need to write your own code to handle any partitioning on the device, and read and parse the file system's structures (directory entries, etc); using BIOS services to read/write raw disk sectors.

b) if your code is running on a bare ARM server with access to UEFI services, then you will need to write your own code to read and parse the file system's structures (directory entries, etc); using UEFI services to read/write raw sectors of the volume.

c) if you're running in a "Linux like" environment (including WSL on Windows) you'll probably end up either using functions in a shared library (`open()`, `read()`, `write()`, if you want to set access time and/or modification time to "now"); a function in a shared library (`utimes()`, if you want to change modification time or access time to something other than "now"); or maybe not being able to do it at all (if you want to change creation time to something other than "now").

d) if you're running in a "Windows like" environment (including Wine on a Linux-based OS) you'll probably end up either using functions in a dynamically linked library (`open()`, `read()`, `write()`, if you want to set access time and/or modification time to "now"); or one function in a dynamically linked library (`SetFileTime()`, if you want to change creation time, modification time or access time).

e) if you're running on a MIPS CPU built into a ethernet router and want to use networking to change the timestamps of a file on a remote computer's "Windows shared folder", then you'll probably need to learn a lot about how to control the router's hardware (how to send/receive data using ethernet ports) plus a lot about the SMB Protocol and CIFS Protocol; and you probably won't be able to do anything other than changing a file's accessed time or modification time to "now".

Comment: Unix traditionally does not store a file creation time.

Comment: melpomene is correct: inode "ctime" is *change* time, not *create* time.  It's updated by anything that modifies contents of the inode itself, like making another hardlink to the inode.  Or changing permissions.  Or even setting the other 2 times: even as `root` there's no API to set the `ctime`.  [How can I change 'change' date of file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/36021), and setting the other 2 with `utimensat` will update it.

Comment: melpomene is correct in that traditionally "historical old Unix" didn't have creation time. However; most modern "Unix like" implementations (e.g. Linux) do support creation time if the underlying file system does; and most modern file systems (e.g. ext4, etc) do support creation times; therefore any "Unix like" that anyone actually cares about today is likely to support creation times.

Comment: Ironically; it's the accessed time that's more likely to not work - for performance reasons and/or to avoid wear on SSD, lots of people disable it with mount options.

Comment: @Brendan http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/ says create-timestamps were new in EXT4, not present in EXT3.  (I hadn't known it existed, so thanks for pointing it out.)  Are you sure most other modern FSes like XFS and BTRFS also have create times?  I found [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562) which has some info.  XFS didn't, at that time, but BTRFS does.

Comment: Oh, and Linux 4.11 does have a `statx` system call which can return the birth time.  [Birth is empty on ext4](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/407305)  `stat` from coreutils 8.31 (March 2019) uses it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I (privately) use "Unix-like" as a derogative term because there's no leadership/consensus and no effective standards (SYSV and POSIX specs transitioned from "too little too late" last century to "rotting towards obsolescence" this century); so it doesn't surprise me that support for anything from the last ~50 years is "partial at best". It's also why I suspected the only way to change creation time (where FS supports it) might be a "copy; delete; rename" sequence to effectively replace the entire file with a new copy (to set modification time to "now" without relying on APIs).

Answer (score 2):

The handout you were given could have included details of how to access the timestamp of a given file, as stored in the directory structure of the filesystem (FAT). I assume that you don't want that.

Other than that, you'd want to use an API provided by Windows to get a handle to a file, and then to modify its timestamp.

If you want a good starting point, look at the [SIB: Small is Beautiful starter kit](https://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm); you can [download its ZIP archive directly][SIPzip]. It's a complete 32-bit Windows application written in assembly.

Assembly isn't particularly special: you could write a minimal C program that does what you want, then inspect its assembly listing output to understand what it takes to write such assembly, and then you can redo it from scratch in assembly.

On Windows, the lowest level userspace API is the semi-documented [ntdll.dll](https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/). Your tiny application would link to that dll (and perhaps kernel32.dll) and invoke its functions to do the manipulations you desire. These calls are thin shims to kernel-mode file API, so this is as close to kernel you get without writing actual driver code.

The APIs you'd need are [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntopenfile) to open the file, [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) and [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with [`FileBasicInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class) information class type and [`FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_basic_information) structure, and finally [`NtClose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntclose) to free the handle.

It is the [`FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_basic_information) structure that contains the file stamps you wish to modify.

Since you're doing things at a very low level, the convenience of the C runtime library will not be available if you won't link with it and use it explicitly. Thus it's better to start in C, get it working, and then start slimming it up on the way to assembly.